# firebase persist data with circular reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a simple data that i want to persist on firebase.

This data is a domain class for my relational model (i started with a relational model and now im deciding whenever or not migrate to firebase, but for awhile im working with both... or trying to)

To persist a new instance if my class on firebase i need to do:

```
Map<String, Object> firebase = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            firebase.put("raffleDate", this.giveaway.getRaffleDate());
            firebase.put("thumbnailUrl", this.giveaway.getThumbnailUrl());
            firebase.put("mustFollowList", this.giveaway.getMustFollowList());
            firebase.put("owner", this.giveaway.getOwner());
            firebase.put("amountFriendsToIndicate", this.giveaway.getAmountFriendsToIndicate());
            firebase.put("mediaId", this.giveaway.getMediaId());

            ((App) getApplication()).getFirebase().child("giveaways").child(this.giveaway.getMediaId()).setValue(firebase);
```

because besides these fields `Giveaway` has one last other field which has a circular reference to itself

```
@ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "raffle")
    @Expose(deserialize = false, serialize = false)
    private List<UserOnGiveaway> attendantsTickets;
```

This field maps the relatioship between user and its giveaways, `UserOnGiveaway` class has a reference to `User` and `Giveaway` so when i try to persist i get a very long non compreensive error that I can just guess is due some stackoverflow because of the circular reference

The thing is I DONT REALLY CARE ABOUT PERSISTING THIS FIELD, in my actual "hybrid" archtecture i'm using firebase only to persist data shared among users, individual user data is being stored locally on android sqlite

So i would like to know is there any way i can annotate this field to force firebase ignore it?

or is there any parameter is can set on firebase call to do it?

PLEASE do not suggest `transient` as it will also affect my ORM
PLEASE2 do not suggest changes on domain since i'm giving a try to firebase i wont make any structural changes before decide for it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@Exclude`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) annotation on a field or getter/setter method to omit it from serialization with the Firebase SDK.

Comment: didn't work, now it simple crashes the app and doesn't throw any error... Just to let it clear the oposite operation works just fine (if i try to load from firebase into my domain class)